# Guardar archivo en data/data/package/

Tags: java, android

La función que hago es crear un .PNG de la imagen que selecciono en la Galería, hasta ahora los he estado guardando en la *Memoria Interna* pero ahora quiero guardarlas en *data/data/package/images* pero no sé como hacerlo.

Así hago para guardarlas en la *Memoria Interna*:

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Download/Images");
```

Necesito algo similar pero en la nueva ruta como comento. He probado esto que comenta @Jorgesys pero no me ha funcionado:

```
File dir = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "/data/data/package/Images");
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa [getFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) para obtener el path del almacenamiento interno:

```
// File dir = Environment.getDataDirectory("/data/data/otrointento.dos/Images");
File dir = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "/Images");
```

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta @Jorgesys