# ¿Como puedo acceder a una carpeta en la memoria interna en Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, manejo-de-memoria, android-imageview

No encuentro la forma para acceder a una carpeta en android. Tengo algunas imagenes que copie al crear mi aplicacion en una ruta de la memoria interna, quiero que al presionar un boton se abra esta carpeta, pero no se como hacerlo ni por donde empezar?

Comment: Jean, nuevamente te comento que  es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Para formular una pregunta revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!.

Comment: Jean,  para guardar  o abrir la memoria interna usa getFilesDir() , https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55911/guardar-archivo-en-data-data-package/55924#55924

Comment: ya lo hice, muchas gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 2):

```
public void openFolder(){
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
       +  File.separator + "myFolder" + File.separator);
   intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/csv");
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a empezar

Comment: Hola solamente. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Las respuestas que son solo codigo no son de buena calidad. Has de explicar la resolucion segun la guia [answer]. En este caso respondiste antes de que se cerrara la pregunta (una vez cerrada ya no habrias podido responder) y es que si una pregunta no tiene calidad suficiente es mejor esperar a que el autor la mejore antes de responer, para no promover indirectamente este tipo de preguntas.  Un saludo

Comment: Lo tendre en cuenta para futuras ocasiones

Comment: @solamente gracias por tu contribución, pero el OP desea acceder a la memoria interna, no a la externa ( getExternalStorageDirectory).

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, pero creo que  el getExternalStorageDirectory() sirve para memoria externa o SD, mas no la memoria interna, o me equivoco?, he encontrado mucho ese codigo que me facilitas pero no se si me sirva para la memoria interna?